# MongoDB aggregate group on inner child collection and get count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a User collection, which further have a 'UserSubscription' collection, which further have 'Subscription > Publication'.

I have following User collection in Mongo

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            },
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 2,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 2,
                "Code" : "2MM",
            },      
    },
    {
        "_id" : 7,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 7,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            },      
    }
]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 3,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            }      
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 4,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            }      
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 5,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 5,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 2,
                "Code" : "2MM",
            }      
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to get all 'Publication code' and the Count (User subscribed to Subscription count). So from above collection i want result like this

```
 PublicationCode      Count (Number of users)
 1MM                  3
 2MM                  2
```

I have tried folling MongoDB query but not getting actual result

```
db.runCommand(
{ aggregate : "User", pipeline : [
    {$match: { "UserSubscriptions.0": {$exists: true}} },
    {$group: {_id:"$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication.Code", count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project: {_id:1,count:1 } }
    ]}
);
```

Please advice some way to use group on child collection

(Robo 3T 1.2.1) (MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4)

Corresponding C# Mongo Driver query is

```
var unWind = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "$unwind", "$UserSubscriptions" }
        };
var group = new BsonDocument
            {{"$group",
                new BsonDocument
                {{ "_id", new BsonDocument {{"id", 
"$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication.Code"}, }},
                {"Count",  new BsonDocument {{"$sum", 1}} }}
            }};

var pipeline = new[] { unWind, group };
var ff = _readOnlyAccess.GetDatabase(this._Database).GetCollection<T> 
(this._Collection).Aggregate<T>(pipeline);
```

Resulted in error

FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'Int32' from BsonType 'Document'.

Comment: Add `$unwind` stage after `$match`. Something like `{$unwind:"$UserSubscriptions"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Also, there's no need to use that `$match` - `$unwind` will skip empty arrays by default.

```
db.getCollection('User').aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$UserSubscriptions'},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication.Code',
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }}
])
```

**EDIT:** Above will count multiple codes in customer multiple times, so here's an updated version:

```
db.getCollection('User').aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$UserSubscriptions'},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$_id',
    codes: {$addToSet: '$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication.Code'}
  }},
  {$unwind: '$codes'},
  {$group: {
    _id: '$codes',
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Radoslaw, adding $unwind still result incorrect count, here a user can have multiple subscriptions with same publication code and in such case count is coming 2 as it should be 1. Moreover can you please suggest mongo driver query for above aggregate method, i tried (see my updated question with mongo driver query) and getting error "FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'Int32' from BsonType 'Document'".

Comment: @AnilD: I've updated the answer. I won't be able to write it in this C# driver as I don't know its API, but this code works in Mongo shell or Robo3T.

Comment: Radoslaw, it works magically.. now just need to convert it to C# query

Comment: Hi Radoslaw, what i need to add in this query to get other columns of Publication collection as well?

Comment: You mean the other fields from `UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication`? You can group them similarly or treat it as a pair, e.g. `[Code, FieldX]`. If you meant a different collection, then you'll have to use `$lookup`.

Comment: But if i add 'UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication' in group doesn't it effect the count?

Comment: It depends. You can add whole object but group by its ID and not the whole.

Comment: Radoslaw, i tried few things like added new set 'pub:{$addToSet: '$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication'}' but it affect the count, how do i achieve this?

Comment: I think you should post a new question.

Comment: Radoslaw, i have tried few things and got it working, i have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298241/mongodb-aggregate-group-on-inner-child-collection-and-get-complete-document-with), m i doing it in right way?