# MongoDB aggregate group on inner child collection and get complete document with count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a User collection, which further have a 'UserSubscription' collection, which further have 'Subscription > Publication'.

Mongo collection looks like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 1,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            },
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 2,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 2,
                "Code" : "2MM",
            },      
    },
    {
        "_id" : 7,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 7,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            },      
    }
]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 3,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            }      
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 4,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 1,
                "Code" : "1MM",
            }      
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "UserSubscriptions" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 5,
        "Subscription" : {
            "_id" : 5,
            "Publication" : {
                "_id" : 2,
                "Code" : "2MM",
            }      
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to get all 'Publications' and the Count (User subscribed to Subscription count). So from above collection i want result like this

```
 PublicationCode      Count (Number of users)
 1MM                  3
 2MM                  2
```

I have tried following MongoDB query and getting result

```
db.runCommand( {
   aggregate: "User",
   pipeline: [
     {$unwind: '$UserSubscriptions'},
     {$group: {_id: '$_id',pub: {$addToSet: 
                '$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication'}}},
     {$unwind: '$pub'},
     {$group: {_id: '$pub.Code',pub:{$first:'$pub'}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
     {$project:{_id:0,"Publication":"$pub","count":1}}
 ]} )
```

Corresponding C# Mongo driver code is

```
 var unwind = new BsonDocument { { "$unwind", "$UserSubscriptions" } };
        var group1 = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$group",
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "_id", "$_id"
                            },
                            {
                                "publications", new BsonDocument
                                             {
                                                 {
                                                     "$addToSet","$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication"
                                                 }
                                             }
                            }
                        }
              }
            };
        var unwindCode = new BsonDocument { { "$unwind", "$publications" } };
        var group2 = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$group",
                    new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "_id", "$publications.Code"
                            },
                            {
                                "Publications", new BsonDocument
                                             {
                                                 {
                                                     "$first","$publications"
                                                 }
                                             }
                            },
                            {
                                "NumberOfUsers", new BsonDocument
                                             {
                                                 {
                                                     "$sum",1
                                                 }
                                             }
                            }
                        }
              }
            };

        var project = new BsonDocument
        {
            {
                "$project",
                new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"_id", 0},
                        {"Publication","$Publications"},
                        {"NumberOfUsers", 1},
                    }
            }
        };

        var pipeline = new[] { unwind, group1, unwindCode, group2, project };
        List<BsonDocument> docs= coll.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline);
```

Resulted 'Count' is coming correct with 'Publication' document.
But the query is taking some time to return the result. For 50K Users records it is taking around 23 secs.

Please advice some way to improve the performance of the MongoDB query

(Robo 3T 1.2.1) (MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4)

Comment: Can you check native mongo query? How much time it is taking to get result?
Sometime memory leak hppen when try to fetch data using thrid party lib.

I had this problem when try to search data from mongodb using spring-mongo lib.

Comment: Might  this will help you https://mongoplayground.net/p/R7lFAdbakVB... Reducing atleast two stages for you...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet i want to return complete 'Publication' document with count, so that's why added 2nd group

Comment: Your pipeline doesn't return that as well... And you asked for query performance not for the publication fields that's why I have suggested you... BTW You can use `$first` to get your publication fields at second stage of `$group`

Comment: My pipeline is returning that, please see i have used same `{$group: {_id: '$pub.Code',pub:{$first:'$pub'}, count: {$sum: 1}}}`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you need to go through whole collection (in this situation you can't use the indexes for the process speed up).

You can try this code (it have less operation that your):

```
db.getCollection('User').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$UserSubscriptions"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id:"$UserSubscriptions.Subscription.Publication.Code",
            users: {$addToSet: "$_id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {"PublicationCode": "$_id", "Count": {$size: "$users"}}
    }
])
```